# BeautifulSoup: find_all() returns one result when using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm practicing web scraping using Beautiful Soup. But it turns out one result only. I checked soup.find_all. When I print out "items", it shows the whole list. However, when I add for loop function, it just shows one result. Please help me thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html_text = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_= '_13oc-S')
for start_scraping in items:
    product_name = start_scraping.find('div', class_ = '_4rR01T').text
    product_price = start_scraping.find('div', class_ = '_30jeq3 _1_WHN1').text
    product_rating = start_scraping.find('div', class_ ='_3LWZlK').text
    product_description = start_scraping.find('li', class_ ='rgWa7D').text

print(f'Product Name: {product_name} \nProduct Price: {product_price} \nProduct Rating: {product_rating} \nProduct Descrption: {product_description}')
```

Comment: Your `print` is not in the `for` loop so it only prints the last one. Either put it in the loop, or put the results in a list and print the list at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The print should be put inside the for loop function. I don't fully understand how for loop works. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add 'print' in the loop not out of that
better approach is pandas:

```
main_list=[]
for start_scraping in items:
    product_name = start_scraping.find('div', class_ = '_4rR01T').text
    product_price = start_scraping.find('div', class_ = '_30jeq3 _1_WHN1').text
    product_rating = start_scraping.find('div', class_ ='_3LWZlK').text
    product_description = start_scraping.find('li', class_ ='rgWa7D').text
    main_list.extend([product_name ,product_price ,product_rating ,product_description ])
df=pandas.DataFrame(main_list)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does work. But I am still a beginner and I am not comfortable with using pandas.

Comment: Dear @hectorcchan, I think you should learn pandas. pandas is very useful and handy when scrape data.